# Skforecast library

Tags: python

I am trying to install in jupyter (python), with anaconda prompt, skforecast library.

LINK: https://github.com/JoaquinAmatRodrigo/skforecast
https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py27-forecasting-series-temporales-python-scikitlearn.html

Here you can see how to install and the requirements, but when i use pip install comand, it gives me error with tqmd library.

Someone has this library and could solve the issue or tell me how to install or something?
Thank you

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: python 3.9.7. i work wtih jupyter (anaconda 3)

Comment: i just created a new fresh conda env `conda create -n test python=3.9.7` activated the session `conda activate test` and then run `pip install skforecast==0.4.1` and it worked fine. Maybe you have some other dependencies that trigger the error?

Comment: with the enviroment worked too me too. Trying other ways, if you use pip3 or " pip install _____ --user, it works